# Codeigniter dropdown only retrieve last data from db

Tags: codeigniter, dropdownbox

I use CI form with `form_dropdown` helper and tried to pull Mysql data into its options, from the below code, its only retrieve the last record from db into the option list?

please advise what is wrong with my code?

**Model**

```
 public function getStates() {
    $query = $this->db->get('states');
    $return = array();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $return[''] = 'please select';
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
            $return[$row['state_id']] = $row['state_name'];
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

**Controller**

```
$this->load->model('db_model');

$data['options'] = $this->db_model->getStates();

$this->load->view('create_new', $data);
```

**View**

```
$state = array(
'name' => 'state',
'id' => 'state',
//'value' => set_value('state', $state)
);

<?php echo form_label('State', $state['id']); ?>
<?php echo form_dropdown($state['name'], $options); ?>
<?php echo form_error($state['name']); ?>
<?php echo isset($errors[$state['name']])?$errors[$state['name']]:''; ?>
```

Comment: Do you got any errors? what was the output?

Comment: Could it be that all your rows have the same `state_id` and overrides each other? What value does `$query->num_rows()` give?

Answer (score 0):

send full query result from the model to the view like this

**Model**

```
 public function getStates() {
    $query = $this->db->get('states');
    return $query->result();
}
```

let the **controller** as it is and now you can populate states in dropdown like this:

**View**

```
<?php
foreach($options as $opt){
  $options[$opt->state_id]=$opt->state_name;
}
echo form_dropdown($state['name'], $options);
?>
```

Comment: I get this error: `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Comment: change `echo form_dropdown($state['name'], $options);` to `echo form_dropdown($options[0]->state_name, $options);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getStates() {
    $return = array();
    $query  = $this->db->get('states')->result_array();
    if( is_array( $query ) && count( $query ) > 0 ){
        $return[''] = 'please select';
        foreach($query as $row){
            $return[$row['state_id']] = $row['state_name'];
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```